# Calculate compound interest rate in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Assume the PV=100, FV=150, yearly IR=X, number of period = 60 (5 years of interest and compounding is monthly basis)

Therefore:

```
FV = PV * (1 + X / 12)^60
```

How can I calculate X easily?

Technically I can use `(root(FV/PV))-1)*12`, where `root(N)` is the 60th root of N. But is there any existing function I can use such as PV and FV?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, and it's called [`RATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093257?hl=en). Example of usage:

```
=RATE(60,0,-100,150)
```

calculates the percentage required for growing $100 to $150 over 60 interest payment periods, while taking out $0 each period. The answer is `0.68%`. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100*%281%2B0.68%2F100%29%5E60) agrees.

The complete list of financial functions in Google Spreadsheets is [here](https://support.google.com/docs/topic/3105398).